# use InDesign vb.net

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2017, adobe-indesign

I would like to develop a tool with visual studio 2017 that merge some csv files with InDesign templates. I've installed InDesign CS5

My main issue is that I can't figure out how to import the InDesign Library. It doesn't work when I use `myInDesign = CreateObject("InDesign.Application")` and when I try to load the file "Resource for visual basic.tlb" it fails and asks me to check if the file is accessible and is a valid assembly or COM component.

What am I missing?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Remove the file *"Resource for visual basic.tlb"* under the map *"C:\ProgramData\Adobe\InDesign\Version 14.0\nl_NL\Scripting Support\14.0".*

Start Indesign as administrator and Indesign will automacilly create the file *"Resource for visual basic.tlb".*

Now that will work.